# Weed Aroma/Flavor?

Tags: hops, aroma, flavor, ingredients

I have noticed in some beers, (nugget nectar, dbl. trouble, founders harvest and sublimely self-rightous ale in particular) an aroma/flavor of marijuana.  I think Columbus/Tomohawk hops have somthing to do with this (I could be wrong).

If someone could shed some light on this subject matter, as to which hop varietals lend this aroma/flavor, it would be quite enlightening...

Answer (score 5):

Considering that hops are from the same family (Cannabaceae) as marijuana and hemp, that's not as outrageous as it may seem. Summit hops in particular, have an intensely 'weedy' aroma. I had an all Summit IPA shortly after the hop was introduced and it smelled (and tasted a bit) like bong water.

Comment: Agreed on the Summit. I used some in a black IPA yesterday, and when I opened the pouch it smelled like citrus weed. As did my basement.

Comment: thanks...not familiar with that particular varietal, but I will have to check it out.